# PsExec returning "the system cannot find the file specified"

Tags: windows, command-line, psexec

I am trying to open a program remotely from another pc. I am using this command for psexec:

```
psexec.exe -accepteula -s -d -i 2 -w C:\Tools \\192.168.1.1 -u Login -p Pass C:\Tools\program.exe
```

If I issue this command the response is "the system cannot find the file specified", but I assure you, the file is there on the pc this command is being sent to. The pc I am issuing this from is windows 7 and the pc receiving this command is windows 8.1. This same command works going from windows 7 to windows 7. Is there something I can change in my command to get this to work in windows 8.1? I have read that older versions of psexec could fix this issue, but I can't find any downloads earlier than 2.44.

Comment: First thought: are you sure session 2 is active?  ERROR_FILE_NOT_FOUND doesn't always mean a missing file, it can mean a missing object of any kind.

Comment: I'm not exactly sure what you mean, but if i use just "-i" it doesn't start the program. It will state that it started it, but it doesn't. I want the program to start on the pc i'm sending the command to.

Comment: It *does* start the program, it just isn't visible.  If you want the program to be visible to the logged-on user, you have to find out which session the user is logged into and specify that number on the command line.  (The "details" tab in Task Manager has an optional column for the session ID.)  Most often, the interactively logged-on user is in session 1.

Comment: Ok, so I want it to be visible on the \\192.168.1.1  machine how do I find out what session to start it on?

Comment: I'm now finding out that this command works on some windows 7 machines and not others...all are setup the same.

Comment: You can find out which session you are logged into using Task Manager.  On Windows 8, this is an optional column on the details tab.  Programatically, you can use WTSGetActiveConsoleSessionId, WTSEnumerateSessions, or QueryTokenInformation, depending on which direction you're coming from.

Comment: I can't thank you enough harry. Now that I know how that works and how to find the session id it works and i can now have my program prepared for any session id. thank you so much.

Comment: @HarryJohnston, it's Win32 `GetTokenInformation`, while the system call is `NtQueryInformationToken`.